# Populate Meta Tag Dynamically

Tags: channel-entries

I want to be able to populate my meta tags with the information for the specific page that the user is visiting.  I obviously can't just plug a variable in there without it being in some kind of a channel entries loop, but I don't want to have to specify the channel because that defeats the purpose of having it dynamically populated.  Is there a way to grab the channel based on the page the user is on?  I'd basically want to have something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{channel}"}
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />
...etc.
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I'd use SEO Lite - then only this is needed in the header:

```
{exp:seo_lite use_last_segment="y"}
```

And then this in the config file / SEO Lite template:

**EE2 example** (with focuslab llc master config):
https://gist.github.com/bjornbjorn/4039233

**EE3 example** can be found here: http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/extra-tags

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite

.. but then again I might be biased as I'm the dev behind the addon ;-)

Comment: If I could up-vote this answer more than once, I would.

Comment: Can you give any clarity to the seo_lite config file you posted a link to?  I am researching your solution a bit deeper and I don't understand how to implement the array you posted a link to.  When I try and look at the markup, the extra fields show up as {extra:desc}.  I'm not sure where the "extra" part of that tag is coming from?  any clarification you can provide would be great.

Comment: I always use FocusLab's Master Config, which makes it easy to have multiple installations (local, staging, prod) and one config for each. However, if you don't that code would go in system/expressionengine/config/config.php and the array would be named $config not $env_config. That array is basically a PHP array of channel_id's (the database id of each channel) and then the field_id's (the database id of the custom field) for the various "extra tags" (ie. desc, image). That way SEO Lite knows where to pull the og:image, og:description from for each channel entry.

Comment: that works perfectly!  awesome! I'm not sure what's supposed to happen here, but I think after looking at both solutions provided here, yours is a better fit for my situation, unfortunately I had already marked Derek Hogue's answer as correct.  One last question.  How can I override the {extra:desc} tag for a single template?

Comment: {extra:desc} can't be overridden as it is now, but you can use conditionals in the template as you usually do .. normally if you hook it up to a custom field though it will just be empty if that is left empty .. what's the use-case you have for this if you don't mind me asking? .. btw it is possible to change the accepted answer according to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: the reason I was asking is that all my descriptions are showing up correctly now on all my pages, but not the home page of the site.  The main page just pulls a random description from one of the other pages and doesn't use the meta description for the site.  I was thinking the easiest way would be to add the home page to the array in the config file, but I don't know what the channel id is since its not technically a channel...or is it?

Comment: Aha, I see, that's a good point - I'll add that to my todo-list. A quick solution for now could be to use a conditional in your SEO Lite template (edited in Addons -> SEO Lite) -- like this: 

{if segment_1 != ''}
<meta property="og:title" content="{entry_title}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{extra:desc}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{extra:image}"/>
{/if}

That way it won't show those fields on the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

I usually embed the "header" portion of each page, since most of that content is universal. So in this case, you can just use [embed parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template) to pass any meta tags dynamically.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo"}
    {embed="_global/_header" title="{title}" description="{page_summary}" thumbnail="{page_thumbnail}"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    // etc
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in your **_header** template:

```
// opening html tag, etc
<meta name="og:title" content="{embed:title}" />
<meta name="og:description" content="{embed:description}" />
<meta name="og:image" content="{embed:thumbnail}" />
<meta name="description" content="{embed:description}" />
<meta name="thumbnail" content="{embed: thumbnail}" />
<title>{if embed:title}{embed:title} - {/if}My Great Site</title>
```